# Как сделать разделение кнопок в сообщении телеграм бота?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Не могу понять, как разбить кнопки под сообщением на строки и колонки, бот просто выводит сообщение с кнопками в ряд (и то больше 8 кнопок в ряд все влезают)[image: Нужно, чтобы кнопки 4 и 5 были во 2 ряду]

```
$inline_keyboard_questions_account = [[['text' => '№1', 'callback_data' => 'question 1'], ['text' => '№2', 'callback_data' => 'question 2'], ['text' => '№3', 'callback_data' => 'question 3'], ['text' => '№4', 'callback_data' => 'question 4'], ['text' => '№5', 'callback_data' => 'question 5']]],
            'reply_markup' => inline_keyboard($inline_keyboard_questions_account)
```

Нужно, чтобы кнопки 4 и 5 были во 2 ряду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> 'callback_data' => 'question 3'], ['text' => '№4',
> ```

```
'callback_data' => 'question 3']], [['text' => '№4',
```